# UITableView() not showing in UIViewController while trying to add it programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So basically I am trying to use a UITableView within a ViewController that will be referencing views from other UIViews.

All the views are showing and everything seems fine except for the TableView. I have set the tableView.datasource and tableView.delegate to self. I also checked if I have used the same reuse identifier.

Error: All views are being rendered but the table view is just black. Here is the code:

```
class MController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    let customNavBar = NavBarView()
    let statusBarCover = UIView()
    var tableView = UITableView()
    lazy var kView: UIView = {
       return InputView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 100))
    }()

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return kView
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.contentInset.top = 120
        tableView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.top = 120
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")

        view.addSubview(customNavBar)
        customNavBar.backgroundColor = .yellow
        customNavBar.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 0, height: 120))

        view.addSubview(statusBarCover)
        statusBarCover.backgroundColor = .blue
        statusBarCover.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Testing"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you have never defined the size of your table view.

Well actually, first, you don't even add your table view as a subview. Second, even if you do that, there is another issue: navbars and stuff have their default size and position; however, table views do not. I'm almost certain that if you launch the view debugger, you will be able to see the table view in the view hierarchy, but not on the screen, because by default, it's width and height are zero. You need to either manually set the frame in your `layoutSubviews()` method or set up constraints on the table view in `viewDidLoad()` so that it's size will be larger than zero.

TL;DR: views usually do not "just" know how large they should be and where they should go.

Comment: Yes I just fixed it by adding it as a subview and adding anchors to it. Works fine now. I assumed that when we add table view delegates and datasource and initialise a tableview inside the controller and set it's content inset height, it should just work. Understood now that it too acts as a separate view with height and width